# How to select one column and do group by this column in JPA?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I need to do sth like

```
select city from users group by city;
```

How to perform this with Spring JPA? Maybe Specifications? What about something like select according to passed parameter?

```
List<Object> getValuesGroupedBy(String columnName);
```

I tried to use Specification, you can only do

```
query.groupBy(root.get(column));
```

and this really groups by the specified column.

But when you try to do a select

```
query.select(root.get(column)).groupBy(root.get(column))
```

It does sth unreal.

Or, I have also tried to use Projections. I say ok, I need city

```
interface OnlyCity {
   String getCity();
}
```

Then my JPA looks the following:

```
List<OnlyCity> findAllBy();
```

And this selects only one column, which is also OK. But how to put specification there, so I can at least perform the operation I described above?

Comment: you can do it with named queries

Comment: @HadiMoloodi any example?

Comment: Isn't `select city from users group by city;` like `select distinct city from users;` ?

Comment: you cannot put column name as a parameter to @Query

Comment: @Selaron otherwise I have to write 20 different queries for 20 different columns

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this using JPA. Of course, my code designed for Ejb but the main concepts are the same.

```
@Entity
@Table
@NamedQuery(name="groupBy",query="SELECT c.city from City c group by c.city")
class City{
            String city;
            ....
            ....
        }



class CityManager{
            @PersistenceContext
            EntityManager manager

            public List<String> groupBycity()
            {
                return manager.createNamedQuery("groupBy").getResultList();
            }
        }
```

Comment: So, there is no parametrised version of this? I have to write 20 queries for 20 different columns because I want to select data from only one column depending on my parameter.

Comment: good point. To my knowledge, there is no parameterized version.

Comment: Ok, so now main question is how to select one column using Criteria Query. Because we are able to do group by.